# Extracting properties from a Groovy object causes H2 database error

Tags: eclipse, grails, groovy, h2

I'm using Grails 2.0, Groovy 1.8.4 on Eclipse STS 3.7. When I execute the following statement to extract properties from a groovy object, Grails throws a SQL exception, not sure why since I'm not using H2 database. I've deleted `DataSources.groovy` from my project and commented out all references to `sql` or `h2` in other config files, but the problem persists

```
Note note = [title:'foo', details:'bar']
def objprops = note.properties.findAll{ !['class','metaClass'].contains(it.key)}
```

The exception...

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "NOTE" not found; SQL statement:
select this_.id as id0_0_, this_.version as version0_0_, this_.details as details0_0_, this_.title as title0_0_ from note this_ [42102-147]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:327)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:167)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:144)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:4562)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableFilter(Parser.java:1020)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimpleFromPart(Parser.java:1622)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:1729)
```

Comment: The exception is from H2. It seems you didn't comment out H2 in _all_ config files, otherwise it wouldn't use H2.

Comment: Actually, I did, but apparently this has more to do with using the `domain` project folder. I removed my classes from `domain` and used `/src/groovy/mypackage...` instead, problem solved. thx